# University Bitcoin event ideas

Tags: adoption

Can you give me ideas for interesting Bitcoin-related events/projects that I could launch at my university in order to attract people to the club?

Comment: Anyone have ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Wear a Bitcoin shirt (people will ask ;))
- Have a Bitcoin themed party in a student bar
- Offer a Bitcoin meetup
- Walk around on Campus with a sign "Ask me anything about Bitcoin"
- Start a Bitcoin student club
- Convince a Campus shop to accept Bitcoin
- Convince a food delivery service close to campus to accept Bitcoin
- Offer a competition where you offer a price in Bitcoin
- Organize a Presentation/Lecture/Panel about Bitcoin
- Write an article for your student newspaper/newsletter
- Organize a viewing of one of the Bitcoin documentaries on campus